# How to return For function on new function?

Tags: javascript

I want to repack/create new **For** version for more shorthand use.

the currenly my code:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

function loop(v){
return for(i=0; i<v; i++){ function(){}}
}

loop(5){ console.log(i);}

</script>
```

I repack **For** on new function call **loop**. how to do this?

nb: answer it on basic operator solve not function. i think its about closure.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: #PM 77 it used for short-hand use when application need loop too many for reduce size codes

Comment: It doesn't make sense to tag other languages here because every language is different.

Comment: #Felix Kling i think its about alogrithm cause all modern language have same structure. i have update my question.

Comment: Nope, it's not. `loop(5){ console.log(i);}` is not valid JS syntax and there is no way to use this syntax without a pre-processor. If it's just about the functionality (the "algorithm"), then xdazz already provided the only correct answer.

Comment: #Felix King console.log(i) is just ex function. let's say change it to other function like `document.write(i)` in JavaScript, `echo(i)` in PHP. its just function. what i want is alorightm. so why i think other modern language have the same way to repack without involve other function.  try to look my code. i have just updated it.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you want. If you want to say "execute the function F n times", then you have to create a function that accepts F and n as arguments (in JS at least). And that's exactly what xdazz showed you. Note: I have no idea what you mean by "repack". I think you are confusing/mixing the behavior (algorithm) with syntax (the `loop(5){ console.log(i);}`). Those have nothing to do with each other. The same algorithm can look differently in different languages because the syntax is different.

Answer (score 5):

You could pass as a callback.

```
function loop(a, callback){
  for(var i=0; i<a; i++){ 
    callback(i);
  }
}

loop(5, function(i) {
  document.write(i);
});
```

Comment: #xdazz thank you. i realize how addEventListener to be created. i stills need straight answer. to use new loop like usual function. `loop(5){documentwrite(i)}`

Comment: @DavidSlavalia: You can't define your own syntax in JS. You could use a pre-processor such as http://sweetjs.org/, which adds macros.